# Android error reading file from storage

Tags: android, file, permissions

I am trying to read a file into a bitmap and I am getting this exception.  I have checked the location and the file is there.  I am able to write the file to that location, just not read it back.

```
E/BitmapFactory(23020): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
file:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPG_20150322_150618_-1377838390.jpg: 
open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I have the correct permission in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Here is the code that creates the file path

```
File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File image = File.createTempFile(timestamp, ".jpg", storageDir);

mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
```

Here is the code that reads the file:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file:
```

is not needed at all.  The correct path is:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPG_20150322_150618_-1377838390.jpg
```

Everything works fine now

Answer (score 0):

your path is wrong

Use file:// instead of file: or no need to add append this

Comment: actually WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE implies that you can use READ_EXTERNAL STORAGE

Comment: I didn't no this.. Share me the ref doc if you know

Comment: Please remove the misinformation on permissions from this, then the remaining point about the path is a useful answer.